# $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-(2|x|^a+3|y|^b)}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

As you see from the title, I'm asked to compute for which $a,b$ the following integral converges:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-(2|x|^a+3|y|^b)}dxdy$$
By parity argument we can say that: 
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-(2|x|^a+3|y|^b)}dxdy=4\int_{\mathbb{R}_+\times \mathbb{R}_+} e^{-(2|x|^a+3|y|^b)}dxdy$$
and I thought that we might move to common exponent by putting $u=x$ and $v^{\frac{b}{a}}=y$:
$$4\int_{\mathbb{R}_+\times \mathbb{R}_+} e^{-2|x|^a+3|y|^b}dxdy=\frac{4a}{b}\int_{\mathbb{R}_+\times \mathbb{R}_+}v^{\frac{a}{b}-1}e^{-(u^a+v^a)}dvdu$$
but I don't really know how to proceed. Can you help please?

Comment: you can use Tonelli's theorem to simplify the integral to two separated Gaussian-like integrals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start from
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-w^\alpha}\,dw =\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{0}^{+\infty}z^{1/\alpha-1}e^{-z}\,dz = \Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$$
which holds for any $\alpha>0$, then apply your symmetry argument and Fubini's theorem.